# USB Thumb Drive partioned oddly

Tags: linux, partitioning, usb-3

Somehow my 32gb Lexar thumb drive got partioned very strangely, here is the output of lsblk:

```
sdb             8:16   1  29.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1          8:17   1    44M  0 part /media/removable/LEXAR 32GB
├─sdb2          8:18   1    16M  0 part 
├─sdb3          8:19   1   1.3G  0 part 
├─sdb4          8:20   1    16M  0 part 
├─sdb5          8:21   1     2M  0 part 
├─sdb6          8:22   1   512B  0 part 
├─sdb7          8:23   1   512B  0 part 
├─sdb8          8:24   1    16M  0 part /media/removable/UNTITLED
├─sdb9          8:25   1   512B  0 part 
├─sdb10         8:26   1   512B  0 part 
├─sdb11         8:27   1     8M  0 part 
└─sdb12         8:28   1    16M  0 part
```

In my file manager it says I have two drives, the 44M one and the 16M one.

I am a bit of a linux noob so if anybody could tell me how to consolidate all these partitions into one it would awesome.

Comment: Does the drive have any unalloacted spaced considering your missing 90% of the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, download Gparted from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Else visit gparted.org

Then right click on all the partitions in Gparted and merge them. If you can't merge, delete all the partitions and create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: I deleted all partitions using fdisk then created a new partition using all the space on the drive.

Comment: If you'd like to merge your two accounts, head here: http://superuser.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

Open up your Files application (file manager), and right click your USB. You should see an option of format. This will erase your whole USB, and connect all of your partitions. =)